# How can i print this literal in PrintWriter Java

Tags: java, printwriter, string.format

i´m reading a .xls and there are some lines with a content like "100% CDI".

I tried it:

```
result = String.format(line, "%%")
```

But it throwed a IllegalFormatConversionException.

Comment: `result = line;`? It's not really clear what you're trying to do with this `String.format`.

Comment: The first parameter to `String.format` is the format string. The second parameters and the ones that follow it correspond to each placeholder in your format. The result is the formatted string. Note that if you meant `%%` to be the format, it just prints a `%` and will not include a parameter.

Comment: Please add more code and an explanation, a [mcve] will be best. We don't see any `PrintWriter` here. We don't know what's in `line`. We don't know what you intend the format to create, and where you use `result`. There are not enough details to answer.

Answer (score 0):

please add more details. I am not sure why are you using String.format. You could simply use:

```
String result=line;
```